# Add asterisks to the mandatory fields on Django admin

Tags: django

I want to add asterisks to the mandatory fields on Django admin page.
I add required_css_class='requried' in forms.py.
And add extrastyle to task_change_form.html.

```
{% block extrastyle %}
   {{ block.super }}
   <style type="text/css">
   /* add an asterisk using CSS */
       .required::after {
          content: "*";
      }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
```

What is wrong with me?

Comment: Could you check/post the generated html code of the page, taken from browser's view source option?

Comment: If your field is mandatory, it should display the asterisk. Otherwise you could use `verbose_name` or `label` if you want to add asterisks 'manually'. But please copy your code please.

Comment: When I see the source on browser there is style exactly. But it isn't working.

Comment: @Essex If the field is mandatory it is shown as bold. Could you possibly explain how to use verbose_name?

Comment: Please post your code before. Thanks